# Import 3D model from Garry's Mod (GMod)

Tags: modeling, import

I have a 3D model in [Garry's Mod](https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=4000) ["addon" format](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Workshop_Addon_Creation). 
The model is in a rar file which contains "`*.mdl`", "`*.vtx`" and "`*.vvd`" files (among others).

How can I import this model (and its textures) into Blender?

Comment: (If the question is off-topic or can be clarified, please let me know.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vtx files contain textures, and i think you can easily import/export them using: http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/index.php?c=178#p178 by nem

mdl files are compiled model files (probably for performance reasons), the original source files are in smd format which you can easily import into blender using the official Valve script for the smd format:
http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Blender_Source_Tools

As for the mdl decompiling you can use Crowbar:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Crowbar